# MySQL, copy row with change

Tags: mysql

I have a table that looks like this:

```
| company_id | tag_id | etc... |
|------------|--------|--------|
```

I'd like to create a *new* row with `tag_id` set by me for every `company_id` that's in an array. (For every company that has tag x, assign tag y).

Is this possible in a single query? I've tried this which doesn't seem to work:

```
const query = `
    INSERT INTO company_tag (company_id, tag_id, creator_id, organization_id)
    SELECT company_id, ${database.escape(newTagId)}, ${database.escape(userId)}, ${database.escape(organizationId)}
    FROM company_tag
    WHERE id IN (124, 435, 324)
`;
```

---

EDIT: The above works, just made a silly syntax error, should be `WHERE tag_id IN...`

Comment: Looks good to me.

Comment: @Strawberry made a stupid mistake, should be `WHERE tag_id IN...` 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The above works, just made a silly syntax error, should be `WHERE tag_id IN...`